# Sufficient conditions on the profile curve of a revolution surface to make it of class $C^k$

Tags: geometry, surfaces, differential, solid-of-revolution

I will first introduce my notations then ask my questions. Thank you in advance for your answer.

**Notations:**
Given a surface of revolution $S_\Gamma$ of profile curve $\Gamma$ of class $C^k$ given by

$$\begin{equation}
\Gamma  = (r, z) : [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2 : t \mapsto (r(t), z(t)),
\end{equation}$$
where $r(a)=r(b)=0, r|_{]a,b[}>0 $, one can describe $S_\Gamma$ (excepting the poles) with the local parametrization

$$\begin{equation}
X : ]a,b[ \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3 : (t,\theta) \mapsto (r(t)\cos(\theta),r(t)\sin(\theta), z(t)).
\end{equation}$$

We consider the open set of $S$ containing the poles
$$U_N = \{N\} \cup \{X(s,\theta) | s < a + \varepsilon\}, \; \; U_S = \{S\} \cup \{X(s,\theta)| s > b - \varepsilon\} $$
and the following associated charts
$$\phi_N : U_N \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2 : \begin{cases}
    N \mapsto (0,0),\\
    X(s, \theta) \rightarrow ((s-a) \cos (\theta) ,(s-a) \sin(\theta)),  
    \end{cases}
    \\ \phi_S : U_S \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2 : \begin{cases}
    S \mapsto (0,0),\\
    X(s, \theta) \rightarrow ((b-s) \cos (\theta) ,(b-s) \sin(\theta)).
    \end{cases}
$$

**Questions:**
I have two questions that are strongly related :

- 1. Is $$\mathcal{A}=\{(S_\Gamma\setminus (\{N,S\} \cup X(]a,b[,0)), X|_{]a,b[\times ]0,2\pi[}^{-1}),(S_\Gamma\setminus (\{N,S\} \cup X(]a,b[,1)), X|_{]a,b[\times ]1,2\pi +1[}^{-1}),\\ (U_N, \phi_N),\\ (U_S, \phi_S)\}$$ an atlas of $S_\Gamma$ ? If it's not, can you give me another atlas ? Maybe my chart $\phi_N, \phi_S$ are not good enough...
- 2. What are the sufficient conditions on the profile curve $\Gamma = (r,z)$ in order to have $S_\Gamma$ a surface of class $C^k$ ?

I believe the answer is about the behavior and the regularities of the derivative of $r$ and $z$ at the limits $a$ and $b$, but I can't express it.

Thank you for your answer !

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! <> Scattered comments: (i) IIRC, $S$ stands for both the surface and the south pole. (ii) The chart $X$ omits a meridian; we need another chart to cover it. (iii) If the profile is $C^k$, the portion of $S$ away from the poles is $C^k$. (iv) If the profile does not meet the axis orthogonally, there are cone points at the poles. If the profile does meet the axis orthogonally, then mod details it's necessary and sufficient that the profile together with its reflection across the axis constitute a $C^k$ curve.

Comment: Thank you ! I've do some modification on the formulation in order to trade readability to rigor. 

Concerning (iv), this is exactly where I struggle to write the detail to reach this conclusion ! I do not know how to make appear the condition(s) on the first $k$ derivatives of $r$ and $z$ to make $S_\Gamma$ a surface of class $C^k$. If you have any idea to write it in detail, I will be grateful.